# TypeError: descriptor 'readlines' of 'file' object needs an argument

Tags: python, readlines

I get this error for every time I run this code can someone help me please

I want to get url and use it from my urls list its in text file 
 `sewa.txt`

that is the code

```
#encoding: utf-8
import random  
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

usr = ('')
pwd = ('')
poo =unicode ("","utf-8")
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# or you can use Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://m.facebook.com/groups/192674874113111/')
assert "Facebook" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(22)
File=open('/home/sharkawey/Desktop/sewa','r');
for line in file.readlines():
    driver.get(line)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("lgc_view_photo")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(15)
    driver.find_element_by_name("file1").send_keys("/media/sharkawey/THE HELL/2.jpg")

    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("xc_message")
    elem.send_keys(poo)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("photo_upload")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

that is the error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'readlines' of 'file' object needs an argument
```

Comment: Remember that Python is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this,

```
for line in File.readlines():
```

Since the file object you declared is `File` not `file` . Python is a case-sensitive language, you need to be careful while referring variables.

OR

alternatively you could use `for line in File:` since the file object itself an iterator.

Comment: Alternatively, if I understood the code correctly, he can use only `for line in File:`